# Trying to schedule first cron job, does this schedule look good

Tags: cron

I'm trying to schedule my first cron job:

```
* 0830 * * 1,3,5,0 ls -l
```

I'm expecting the job to run Mon, Wed, Fri, and Sun at 8:30am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
30 8 * * 0,1,3,5 ls -l
```

First the minutes, then hours; allways seperated by a whitespace